# Configuring Maven source directories for a polyglot project

Tags: java, maven, clojure

I have a Maven project (in Eclipse using the m2eclipse plugin) that contains code in two different languages (Java and Clojure).

Ideally I'd like two separate source folders for the two languages:

- src/main/java
- src/main/clj

Eclipse is happy with having two source directories defined in the project. However, as far as I can work out, Maven only supports a single source directory as follows:

```
<build>
  ....
  <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
  ....
</build>
```

If I add a second sourceDirectory to the pom.xml, I get an error.....

Is there a recommended way to configure this kind of polyglot project in Maven?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe you need to do that; the Clojure plugin should already know how to find Clojure source (although IIRC it defaults to src/main/clojure).

See [here](http://alexott.net/en/clojure/ClojureMaven.html) for some details.

Answer (score 2):

Point is, `sourceDirectory` is for Java. Mostly, at least. Clojure sources directory depends on the plugin you use; e.g. https://github.com/talios/clojure-maven-plugin uses the following subtags:

```
<configuration>
  <sourceDirectories>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/clojure</sourceDirectory>
  </sourceDirectories>
  <testSourceDirectories>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/clojure</testSourceDirectory>
  </testSourceDirectories>
</configuration>
```

These are default values, so if you use `clojure` instead of `clj`, you should be just fine without configuration.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I found a reasonably good way of making this work: the trick is to **classify your Clojure source directories as resource directories in Maven**. This way the .clj files get included in the generated .jar as you would expect.

Relevant part of the pom.xml:

```
<build>
        ....
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/clojure</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/clojure</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Build Helper Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/) allows you to add additional source directories.

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>src/main/clj</source>
              </sources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```